# Open fragment from inside of another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

as the questions say I am trying to open a fragment from within another fragment. I have a navigation bar that contains all of my current fragments. However, I would like to open up a separate fragment from within one of these, so that the user can do some stuff (navigate to the contact list fragment and add a new contact thus opening a new fragment to help the user create it). So far when I click my add button, nothing happens (it's supposed to display a new fragment). I have searched around StackOverflow and google, but I can't fix my problem. My onClick() looks like:

```
addbutton = view.findViewById(R.id.addAlarm);
addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        addbutton.setText("hello");

        //this is just a textView for simplicity
        CreateAlarm fragment = new CreateAlarm();                           
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        //transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, new CreateAlarm());
        transaction.add(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

My navigation bar uses main_frame to display my normal fragments. It makes sense to me that that's where I would try to add or replace my new fragment. I believe this could be something that has to do with using a navigation bar maybe since I've never had this problem before.  My implementation seems spot on from what I have seen in explanations. Any tips would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well turns out I was calling the same fragment xml file in my OnCreateView for CreateAlarm instead of the new one, thus why I was not seeing any change. Just took me an entire day, but I will leave this up as an example for other people since my code works (both the replace and add fragment calls work properly).